# how to get the master page from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Say I have an iFrame, I want to access the master page or the owner page.

I'm not entirely skilled at html or website building, if anyone could help tell me how do I do this?

Comment: You mean the parent window? You want to access that parent from the iframe? Are they both yours and on the same domain?

Comment: It's impossible because iframe and main window are located in differrent subdomains

Comment: @dc2 you create link like this in comments: `[link](http://example.com) `

Comment: cosset, you are incorrect to say that you cannot because they are different subdomains. First of all, that isn't discerned by his question, secondly, you are able to get the parent from the iframe regardless of different subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.parent
```

is how you get the parent of the iframe. This isn't a good question though, please read the StackOverflow guidelines before posting questions like this.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry about that.